# Can I generate a random number with the probability distribution of the area under any arbitrary function?

Tags: probability, functions, random

If I want to generate a random number from 0 to 1, for example, if I wanted a uniform distribution, I would give the function $y=1$. If I want a simulated normal bell distribution, I could try something like $\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(2x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-1}{2}$. If I wanted more high numbers to appear, I could do $y=x$, or if lower numbers should appear more frequently, $y=1-x$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "arbitrary function" you mean a pdf or something proportional to it. We can sample any continuous distribution of cdf $F(x)$ by computing $F^{-1}(y)$ for $y\sim U(0,\,1)$, provided $F$ is injective, i.e. the pdf is everywhere non-zero. Even if there are regions where $F'$ vanishes, we can still make it work by computing the least $x$ for which $F(x)=y$.

Comment: Good gen'l ques'n with no easy answ: The exact inverse CDF method requires the inverse CDF (quantile function) be available in closed form. See the 'Box-Muller' transformation to generate standard normal random variables from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ random variables. Sometimes a suitably accurate 'rational approximation' can be found for the quantile function when a closed form is not avail. E.g., R uses Wichura's rational approx which gives norm RVs as close as double precision can accommodate. There are 'acceptance-rejection' meth's for some other families without closed for quantile functions.

Answer (score 0):

From the Caratheodory's Existence Theorem you can deduce that

Given a non-decreasing, right continuous function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists a measure $\mu_F$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, s.t. $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$.

So you need to take care $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}F(x) = 1$. And you are done.